# OpenGl in Android

Tags: android, opengl-es

Can anyone point me to some good tutorials or examples of openGL in android. Everyone I find has packages that don't exist. Example: `import android.graphics.OpenGLContext;` does not exist

Comment: You can start with this http://blog.jayway.com/2009/12/03/opengl-es-tutorial-for-android-part-i/

Comment: find the pdf book "OpenGL®ES 2.0 Programming Guide"

Answer (score 2):

http://www.learnopengles.com/android-lesson-one-getting-started/

Answer (score 0):

INsanityDesign's Android port of NeonHelium's superb OpenGL tutorials helped me a huge lot:

http://insanitydesign.com/wp/projects/nehe-android-ports/

The samples all worked fine on my Optimus LG 2x with Cyanogen 7 (Android 2.3.3) as well as in the emulator (though, it's very very slow). The code samples are very simple, to the point and well commented.